# localhost doesn't show all page and shows sum php code but live web shows the all page perfectly

Tags: php

Localhost doesn't show all pages and shows some php code but my live web file shows all the pages perfectly.
I just can't really understand why...
I'm using Webmatrix as my localhost.

For Example my navigation bar is rendered with php but the rest of the page isn't loading.

In live web it's the same page but the php code renders the page.
I have tried adding includes and changeing paths but it still doesn't work.

You can watch the live site on http://segoma.com/version12

Comment: Will this show anything? ````echo phpversion();````

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini (or use phpinfo() to do it).

If you use <? to open PHP code rather than <?php you must have short_open_tag set to true.  Otherwise the server will treat the PHP code as HTML.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

It is quite likely that the settings on your live server are more lenient than those on your development server.

If your page is like some of the older code on our site you may have some short tags and some normal tags in the same page.

Comment: i have Tried it before that wasn't the case if u can think on something else it will be great

Comment: i can mail it to u if u like to

Comment: Better to post the code here if possible, more eyes will see it.